# How to Determine User Online Status/Offline status using Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to show online status on user's panel when user login admin panel How to do this ?

Does Anybody have an idea please help me ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! please edit your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

**Authentication Directives**

The `@auth` and `@guest` directives may be used to quickly determine if the current user is authenticated or is a guest:

```
@auth
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> 
        Online
    </a>
@endauth

@guest
    // The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```

**Edit** (In case of fetching a list of users )

Step: 1 create a middleware 
Create a middleware LastUserActivity using this command.

```
php artisan make:middleware LastUserActivity
```

Add some code check user online or not

```
\\App\Http\Middleware\LastUserActivity.php

<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use Cache;
use Carbon\Carbon;
class LastUserActivity
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check()) {
            $expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(1);
            Cache::put('user-is-online-' . Auth::user()->id, true, $expiresAt);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Step: 2 Add a class into Kernel

Add a class into Kernel file in middlewareGroups

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

             \App\Http\Middleware\LastUserActivity::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
];
```

Step: 3 Add a function into the User Model

```
public function isOnline()
{
    return Cache::has('user-is-online-' . $this->id);
}
```

Don't forget to add `use Cache;` in `User` Model At the top;

Step: 4 Check user Online or offline in Laravel application
Use the isOnline function in view.

```
@if($user->isOnline())
    user is online!!
@endif
```

[Reference](https://www.codermen.com/blog/94/how-to-check-user-online-or-not-in-laravel)

Comment: Perfect answer! It is working well.